# method to return hashmap from text

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, return

I am trying to write a method that takes an InputStream variable and returns a HashMap back to main. However I'm stuck on how to return the variable of HashMap. New to Java so I do not know what I'm doing wrong.For the return statement: pairsCount cannot be resolved to variable. Thanks in advance.

```
private static Map<String, Integer> getHashMap(InputStream in)
{ 

    if (in != null) 
    {
        // Using a Scanner object to read one word at a time from the input stream.
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);   
        String word;
        System.out.println(" - Assignment 1 -s%n%n\n");
        // Continue getting words until we reach the end of input 
        List<String> inputWords = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (sc.hasNext()) 
        {  
            word = sc.next();       
            if (!word.equals(null)) 
            {
                inputWords.add(word);
            }
        }
        Map<String, Integer> pairsCount = new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<String> it = inputWords.iterator();

        String currentWord = null;
        String previousWord = null;

        Integer wordCount = 0;
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            currentWord = it.next();
            if( previousWord != null ) 
            {
                String key = previousWord.concat( "#" ).concat( currentWord );
            if( pairsCount.containsKey( key ) ) 
            {
              Integer lastCount = pairsCount.get( key );
              pairsCount.put( key, lastCount + 1 );
              wordCount = wordCount + lastCount;
            } 
            else 
            {
              pairsCount.put( key, 1 );
              wordCount =  1;
            }
         }
            previousWord = currentWord;     

     }

    }
    return (pairsCount);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because variable pairsCount is out of its scope.

You define it inside of the if block but trying to return it outside.

So try define Map pairsCount = new HashMap<>();
before the  if (in != null)

Comment: That seems to help with my return statement in my method, but my variable pairsCount inside main still cannot be resolved. Shouldn't this variable be returned back if main is calling the method?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)
    {

  InputStream in = System.in;
  in = getFileInputStream(args[0]);
  getHashMap(in);
  
  for( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : pairsCount.entrySet() )
   {
      System.out.printf( "%s %s -> %d\n", entry.getKey().split( "#" )[0],
      entry.getKey().split( "#" )[1], entry.getValue() );
 
   }
    
    }

Comment: First of all. I think you should edit your original post to include the main function as code snippet as well.  Secondly, one more problem is that you cannot say Map<String, Integer> pairsCount = new HashMap<>();  . You need to specify the Type for constructor. So should be Map<String, Integer> pairsCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Comment: To your reference problem, in your main function, you don't have a variable to receive the return value of the function getHashMap(in). So you need to use pairsCount = getHashMap(in);